# Graphing a probability density function in Python

Tags: python, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I need to graph the probability density function of the time independent Schrödinger equation in Python. I need to do this by using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (eigenfunctions) of the equation.

I had no problem solving for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I have no idea how to graph them, and I have tried many different ways. Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem?

The graph should be plotted once for each energy level (n). I have two lists, one for the eigenvectors and one for the eigenvalues (only the real component of each). Both lists are sorted in numerical order relative to the eigenvalues, such that the list of eigenvectors is sorted so that `eigvects[0]` is associated with `eigvals[0]`.

Below is the relevant parts of my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
from math import trunc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#infite square well from 0 to 1

upper=1
lower=0

#step size t

t=10


...  #in this omitted block, the gradient is computed


#D is the gradient 

D*=1/(dx*dx)

#hamiltonian operator

H=-.5*D

#solves the eigenvalues and eigenvectors

eigs=linalg.eig(H)

eigvals=np.real(eigs[0])
eigvects=np.real(eigs[1])


... #in this omitted block, the two lists are sorted


plt.plot(range(0,n),eigvects[0]) #I thought this would graph the probability density function for the first energy level, but it just graphs nonsense
plt.show()
```

I have confirmed that my eigenvalues and eigenvectors are correct.

I'm trying to get the graph looking like this (not the formatting, just the curve):

[image]

I don't need my code written for me, I'd just really appreciate a clue on where to start when graphing these. Thanks!

Here is an example list of eigvals and an example list of eigvects when t=3, as per a question in the comments:

```
eigvals=[1.1715728752538097, 3.9999999999999996]

eigvects=[array([-0.5       ,  0.70710678,  0.5       ]), array([  7.07106781e-01,   4.05925293e-16,   7.07106781e-01])]
```

Comment: What are you doing exactly when you sort them? Is `eigvects` a list of floats?

Comment: The sort is a bit complicated because I want eigvects to be in the same order as eigvals. I sort them by forming tuples with each eigenvalue and it's associated eigenvector, then sorting them based on the eigenvalue and then stripping the values back into their respective lists. `eigvects` is a list of lists (the inner lists are the normalized eigenvectors/eigenfunctions that `linalg.eig` returns).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this works- in your 2D plot, what are the X and Y values?

Comment: The sorting is not really complicated: `val, vec = np.linalg.eig(H)`, then `s = np.argsort(val)`, `val = val[s]` and `vec = vec[:, s]`. Now you have sorted the eigenvalues, stored the order in `s` and rearranged the eigenvectors (which are stored in the columns of `vec`) in the same way. Btw, don't you think your Hamiltonian is a symmetric matrix? In that case, you can use `np.linalg.eigh` which works for symmetric matrices, is faster and returns eigenvalues sorted. Now, if your eigenvalues and eigenvectors have been confirmed correct... what's the problem?